# c# Word-AddIn recognize ribbon-tab spelling

Tags: c#, tabs, word-addins, spelling

Different Word versions have different tab spelling. Some have the whole label as uppercase and others have just the first letter.
I want know how I can recognize the spelling and change my tab label to the same case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this `this.Application.Version` you cab check the word version. The only thing I am doing then is checking if the version is older than 2013:

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(this.Application.Version) > 150)
{
    Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.WinWorker.Label = "lowercase";
}
else
{
    Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.WinWorker.Label = "UPPERCASE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an XML file containing your ribbon, right? If so, I think your best bet is just to go there, look for your tab element and manually change the text in the label attribute to all uppercase letters.
While it may not be a particularly elegant solution, it should do the job just fine. Only downside I can spot is that your ribbon will also appear in all caps if you go to 'Customize Ribbon' in the settings.

Comment: This won't be the answer, because as I wrote there are different Word versions with different case sensitive. Some versions write "START" and some "Start", so I have to check the spelling somehow.
Meistrrr Temmen

Comment: Then I don't think I can provide a good answer. I've definitely seen my solution in production code, but wether you use it is a question of if you're fine with not optimizing as much for other versions than the one that's mostly used or treated as baseline. The AddIn I've looked at was written with Office 2013 in mind and everything else comes secondary. But isn't there someone at your company with more expierence when it comes to VSTO who you could ask for a solution, mister Crotty?

Comment: No, my company is specialized with VB or C but not with C#. But there is this guy with the name Temmen. He should know a little of C# and Word. I will ask him tomorrow, until then, thank you Temmen.